# Why does recursion occur even if the while loop's condition is now satisfied?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop, infinite-loop

```py
    questions = ["Python is a coding language \n [1] True \n [2] False", "There are this many coding languages \n [1] 5 \n [2] 3 \n [3] 17 \n [4] Over 500 \n", "question 3", "question 4", "question 5", "question 6", "question 7", "question 8", "question 9", "question 10",]
    
    answers = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",]
    
    asked_questions = []
    Number = 0
    import random
    def quiz():
      global questions
      global answers
      global asked_questions
      global Number
      while Number != 10:
        randomnumber = random.randint(0,9)
        random_question = questions[randomnumber]
        asked_questions.append(randomnumber)
        for alreadyaskedquestions in range(len(asked_questions)):
          if randomnumber == asked_questions[alreadyaskedquestions-1] and asked_questions[alreadyaskedquestions] != 0:
            del(asked_questions[-1])
            quiz()
        print(random_question)
        answer = input("")
        Number += 1
        if answer == answers[randomnumber]:
          print("correct")
        else:
          print("wrong")
    
    quiz()
```

I am creating a quiz program that asks 10 questions in a random order. I want the function to stop after 10 questions have been asked, but the while loop continues to run even after it's condition has been met. I have tried adding print statements and found that in my program, the code does not run the lines before the for loop when 10 questions have been asked, but I'm not sure why or how this would fix the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your call to `quiz()` in the for loop seems out of place. What is the recursion intended for in the code?

Comment: Delete the recursive call

Comment: @ricardkelly Its meant to restart the loop until it generates a number that corresponds to a question that hasn't been asked yet

Comment: @Bohemian how should I have the program choose a question that hasn't been asked if I shouldn't call the function inside itself?

Comment: @ThymeTravler the usual way is to put the questions in a list, then shuffle the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `question` class that has the question text and the answer. Put them a list and randomise the order:

```
import random

random.shuffle(questions)
```

Then ask them looping over the shuffled list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a different way of achieving what you are trying to do:

```
import random

def quiz(questions, answers):
  quiz_remaining = [{'q': questions[i], 'a': answers[i]} for i in range(0,len(questions))]
  question_count = 0
  while question_count < 10:
    question_count += 1
    random_number = random.randint(0,len(quiz_remaining)-1)
    random_quiz = quiz_remaining[random_number]
    del quiz_remaining[random_number]
    print(random_quiz['q'])
    answer = input("")
    if answer == random_quiz['a']:
      print("correct")
    else:
      print("wrong")

questions = ["Python is a coding language \n [1] True \n [2] False", "There are this many coding languages \n [1] 5 \n [2] 3 \n [3] 17 \n [4] Over 500 \n", "question 3", "question 4", "question 5", "question 6", "question 7", "question 8", "question 9", "question 10",]
answers = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",]

quiz(questions, answers)
```

There are some differences between it and your code:

- Using global variables is generally not desirable. It makes your code less portable and often less readable.
- You don't need to recurse into the function to restart, since you already have the while loop.
- If you make a copy of the questions and answers, then remove each as you ask it, then you can just randomly select from the remaining questions rather than needing to check if you asked it already.
- Zipping the questions and answers into a single data structure let's you work with them together.